# text-transform select field browser problems

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change option text to upper case with css text-transform.
Not working in Safari/iphone and not working in firefox/desktop. Does anybody have a solution without using toUpperCase() / javascript ?

```css
select {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">item1</option>
  <option value="">item2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Selects are notoriously iffy for styling - if it doesn't work, then you probably need to use a js plugin to change the look and feel - I usually use [select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Pete

Comment: So are you saying that this works on all other browsers that you've tried, like IE/Edge and Chrome? If this doesn't work *anywhere* then the problem is somewhere else. If you click on the "Run code snippet" in the question, does it work there?

Answer (score -3):

*text-transform* DOES work in both safari 1.0 + and firefox 1.0+ since it belongs to CCS1.

Can you try to use
 `<select style="text-transform:uppercase">` 
instead?

Take into account that there are some languages which are not supported by this style.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

Greets

Comment: thanks for the reply, but unfortunately not working in firefox quantum 63.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, you might need to resort to JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.upper-case-option').forEach(option => {
  option.text = option.text.toUpperCase()
})
```

```html
<select>
  <option class="upper-case-option" value="">item1</option>
  <option class="upper-case-option" value="">item2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: OP specifically says not to use toUpperCase!